# Какое имя окружения (venv) выбрать при создании проекта Django?

Tags: django, virtualenv

При создании виртуального окружения нового проекта Django, выполняя команду `python -m venv <имя_окружения>` для создания окружения, я затрудняюсь с выбором имени окружения, так чтобы это легко воспринималось с первого взгляда.

К примеру я начинаю новый проект, example.com, и например выбираю example для окружения и для имени проекта (`django-admin startproject example`) то получается путь `/Hdd/Projects/Django/example/example`. В голову приходи вариант c *example-project* или  *example-venv*, т.е `/Hdd/Projects/Django/example/example-project`.

Какие имена вы обычно выбираете для окружения и для проекта?

Comment: `env` . . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я обычно создаю `evn2` и `env3`, под соответствующие версии Python.